# Javascript function force downloads an MP3 file from URL, once downloaded however MP3 file wont play on my computer only on VLC Player? Why?

Tags: javascript, html, mp3

I have a Javascript function that basically force downloads a file once provided the URL and name of the file. This function works absolutely fine as intended I call it from a HTML  tag/hyperlink. But once the MP3 file from my function downloads it wont play on my computer. I have designed this function for a user to be able to download different MP3 and WAV files upon clicking on the associated link for that file. I can only play the downloaded MP3 file on the media player VLC it won't play on my laptop. Is there something I am doing to the MP3 file in the download process with my function or why will it not play once downloaded?

I have looked into MP3 file variations and encoding but Im not sure what to look for really or what I am doing wrong. When I download MP3 files from other sites they are working fine and play straight away.

Function:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
function downloadFile(data, fileName, type="text/plain") {
  // Create an invisible A element
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(a);

  // Set the HREF to a Blob representation of the data to be downloaded
  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([data], { type })
  );

  // Use download attribute to set set desired file name
  a.setAttribute("download", fileName);

  // Trigger the download by simulating click
  a.click();

  // Cleanup
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
// ]]></script>
```

Function Call:

```
<a href="javascript:downloadFile('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0037/4951/1217/files/ascence-places-like-that-ncs-release.mp3?360','test.MP3')">My Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the downloaded file, you'll find it contains the text `https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0037/4951/1217/files/ascence-places-like-that-ncs-release.mp3?360` because that's the value you're passing for `data` and using when creating the blob. Nothing about that code creating a blob downloads the content (and the SOP prevents your code from downloading the content, unless of course the other site overrides it with CORS).

I don't think you can force the link to open the Save dialog. Normally that's triggered by the **response** to the link from the server (via the `Content-Disposition` header), which of course you can't control in your scenario. Using the `download` attribute won't do it, it has no effect cross-origin (other than when the link is a `data:` or `blob:` URL, see [MDN's description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)).

You can show them the link so they can right-click and choose "Save target as...", but I know that's going to be a disappointing answer for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! So basically because I can't control the server response in the Content-Disposition Header because I am using Shopify I can't force the link to open the save dialog is what you're saying?

Comment: @A.McKeown - Yes, that's right. (Unless you get a server involved that you can proxy through. :-) )